# WSDL to PHP with Basic Auth

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, basic-authentication

I need to build php classes from a WSDL that is behind basic auth.

It has tons of namespaces so it looks burdensome to do this by hand.

I have tried a few tools but looks like the auth session isn't presistent.

Comment: see this link..... This link may help you .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38784772/5634447

Answer (score 27):

```
$options = array(
     'login' => $username,
     'password' => $password,
);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```

Yes, it works! I tried in a solution that I was building and it connects to my customer WS which is with HTTP Basic Auth.

Comment: This works for authentication in the API, but does not use the authentication to retrieve the WSDL, for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

HTTP Auth works with SOAP Client, however you cannot access password protected WSDL files

See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27777

Comment: Easy solution for the Auth error is to add HTTP auth to the soap stream: ```stream_context_create([
            'ssl' => [
                // set some SSL/TLS specific options
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                'header' => array(
                    "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("user:pass"),
                )
            ]
        ]);```

Comment: @Feras SoapClient won't send the Authorization header

Answer (score 4):

Using built in SOAP client, you should have something like this:

```
$options = array(
    'login' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```

Comment: How is this an answer? According to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27777 HTTP authentication is not supported for WSDL files that way.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by using the lib [nusoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/). See if it helps

```
$params = array(
  "param" => "value"
);

$soap_client = new nusoap_client($wsdl_url, true);
$soap_client->setCredentials(USER_SERVICE, PASS_SERVICE, 'basic');
$soap_client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8'; //Fix encode erro, if you need
$soap_return = $soap_client->call("method_name", $params);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this solution:

1. Download the WSDL and save into a local file
2. Create SoapClient with the local file

Something like this (in a simplified version) :

```
class MySoap {

    private $WSDL = 'https://secure-wsdl.url?wsdl';

    private $USERNAME = 'dummy';
    private $PASSWORD = 'dummy';

    private $soapclient;

    private function localWSDL()
    {
        $local_file_name = 'local.wsdl';
        $local_file_path = 'path/to/file/'.$local_file_name;

        // Cache local file for 1 day
        if (filemtime($local_file_path) < time() - 86400) {

            // Modify URL to format http://[username]:[password]@[wsdl_url]
            $WSDL_URL = preg_replace('/^https:\/\//', "https://{$this->USERNAME}:{$this->PASSWORD}@", $this->WSDL);

            $wsdl_content = file_get_contents($WSDL_URL);
            if ($wsdl_content === FALSE) {

                throw new Exception("Download error");
            }

            if (file_put_contents($local_file_path, $wsdl_content) === false) {

                throw new Exception("Write error");
            }
        }

        return $local_file_path;
    }

    private function getSoap()
    {
        if ( ! $this->soapclient )
        {
            $this->soapclient = new SoapClient($this->localWSDL(), array(
                'login'    => $this->USERNAME,
                'password' => $this->PASSWORD,
            ));
        }

        return $this->soapclient;
    }

    public function callWs() {

        $this->getSoap()->wsMethod();
    }
}
```

It works for me :)

Comment: Basic auth in url has been decracated in rfc3986, so might not work for others and also soon also not for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

**This is Simple example to authenticate webservice using soapClient**

```
$apiauth =array('UserName'=>'abcusername','Password'=>'xyzpassword','UserCode'=>'1991');
$wsdl = 'http://sitename.com/service.asmx?WSDL';
$header = new SoapHeader('http://tempuri.org/', 'AuthHeader', $apiauth);
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl); 
$soap->__setSoapHeaders($header);       
$data = $soap->methodname($header);
```

This code internally parse header as follow

```
<soap:Header>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <UserName>abcusername</UserName>
      <Password>xyzpassword</Password>
      <UserCode>1991</UserCode>
    </AuthHeader>
</soap:Header>
```

Answer (score -1):

i’ve been trying to resolve this issue, but from what i understand, soap client connections to ssl+httpauth web services are more pain. I’ve googled and from what i understand, with my problem being solved, you can use the example below to solve your problem too(by using HttpAuth infos in both url and soapClient setup).

```
$username="test";
$password="test";
$url = "https://".urlencode($username).":".urlencode($password)."@example.com/service.asmx?WSDL";

$context = stream_context_create([
'ssl' => [
// set some SSL/TLS specific options
'verify_peer' => false,
'verify_peer_name' => false,
'allow_self_signed' => true,
]]);

$client = new SoapClient($url, [
'location' => $url,
'uri' => $url,
'stream_context' => $context,
'login' => $username,
'password' => $password
]);

$params=array(
'operation'=>’arguments',
'and’=>'other bull',
'goes’=>'here'
);

$response = $client->__soapCall('OperationName', array($params));
```