# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [ns1:Server.Unauthenticated] php

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I need some help if anyone can. I am trying to get data by SOAP and having difficulties. Any idea?

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://api.propertyware.com/pw/services/PWServices?wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
//var_dump($SOAPLINK);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($client->getBuildingList($orgID));
echo '</pre>';

//echo '<pre>';
//var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); 
//var_dump($client->__getTypes()); 
//echo '</pre>';
```

But getting error

> Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception:
> [ns1:Server.Unauthenticated] User 'null' not authenticated (unknown
> user) in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\test\index.php:10 Stack trace:
> #0 C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\test\index.php(10): SoapClient->__call('getBuildingList', Array)
> #1 {main}   thrown in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\test\index.php on line 10

Comment: What's unclear about "User 'null' not authenticated (unknown user)"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219463/wsdl-to-php-with-basic-auth

Comment: Thats what i am cofused. They give only soap url. I am not sure where to authenticate user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WSDL to PHP with Basic Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219463/wsdl-to-php-with-basic-auth)